# How to detach data disk in Azure SQL VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine

For temporary testing purpose. I created a SQL VM in Azure, and the Azure wizard assign me a OS disk with 127G and a Data disk with 1T. But the cost of the Data disk is a little bit expensive for me. so I change the server default data and log path to OS(C) disk. and backup DB to OS(C) disk. then detach Data(F) disk.

The problem is sql server start fail without data disk. what should I do if I want run sql server without data(F) disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I recall, you dont really need data disk to run sql on azure vm. by default it will use it to host database files, you can move those to disk C and repoint SQL to them. there are many ways to do that, you can consult official docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks, it's works. after set the default data and log folder, the temp db and log file need to move to OS disk. the sql command of moving temp file is l

USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'C:\DATA\tempdb.mdf');
GO

ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'C:\LOG\templog.ldf');
GO

Answer (score 1):

C drive is dedicated for OS. While putting data and log files on the same drive as OS may work for test/dev workloads, it is not recommended to put database files and OS on the same drive for your production workloads. Depending on your VM type, OS drive may use Standard Disks (HDD) or Premium Disks. There are IOPS limit for each of these Disks types. For instance, Standard Disks can support up to 500 IOPS and it is important to keep these IOPS for OS so that OS operations do not have to compete IOPS with other applications. Starving OS operations can result in VM restart.

Please send an email to AzureDisksPM@microsoft.com if you have additional questions.

Thanks,
Aung